# Adding MySql.Data.dll to Qt C++?

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

How do I add a `MySql.Data.dll` file to a Qt C++ project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For QT, check out [QSQL](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/sql-programming.html) instead to connect to a database.

Or use the C++/C connectors:

- For C++: [MySQL++](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/doc/)
- For C: [MySQL C API](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c.html)

Comment: but Why I can't use MySql.Data.dll to connect to MySQL from Qt C++ ?

Comment: Why do you want to? Where did you get that .dll? What project is it part of? Read tamás answer :)

Comment: OK! I used this dll file to connect VS C# application with MySQL, so, I thought I could use it as well to connect Qt C++ with MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the naming of the DLL and a little searching, I suspect that it is a .NET assembly, not a regular win32 dll. Unless you have a good reason to do so, you shouldn't try to use a .NET assembly in a native C++ application. It can be done, but it's messy.

Qt has an [SQL module](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtsql.html) which should be sufficient in 99% of the cases. If you have questions about how to use it (e.g. connecting to a database, doing queries etc.), ask them as separate, specific questions.

Comment: Ok, so, How could I connect Qt C++ with MySQL please?

Comment: Wally, please take some time to read the faq: http://stackoverflow.com/faq
This is not a discussion board but a Q&A site. When I say ask a separate question I mean you should click the ask question button and state your specific question. Don't forget to accept answers to your questions by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Comment: Thanks Tamas, this is my 1st time to use this website! I really sorry.

Comment: Thanks Tamas, this is my 1st time to use this website! I really sorry.